# Частое пробуждение Alarm Manager Google Play

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, google-play

Подскажите что это значит (скрин), и какие способы решения есть, и соответственно из-за чего это может происходить ? Используется реклама `Kidoz`, `Admob`, `Appodeal`, и `local notification`. В интернете толком ничего понятного не обнаружил для себя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alarm Manager используется для *local notification*. Т.е. планируя событие плагин запускает таймер, после срабатывания которого произойдёт появление события. Это же событие может "разбудить" телефон, если тот заблокирован. Если устройство перезапустят все "запланированные" срабатывания удалятся.

В статистике вы, соответственно, видите, что в 5% случаев телефон пробуждался оповещениями 10 раз или больше в час. Соответственно, гугл считает, что это слишком часто и предлагает уменьшить это число.

[Документация Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). В первом же абзаце описано, что это такое и где используется.
[Урок по оповещениям. В том числе и про AlarmManager](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html)